# Leetcode 27. Remove Element: Execution time for the same submission differs drastically

Tags: c++, big-o

[Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/):

> Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that
>   value in-place and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Given nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3,
>
> Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of
>   nums being 2.
>
> It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length. Example
>   2:
>
> Given nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2], val = 2,
>
> Your function should return length = 5, with the first five elements
>   of nums containing 0, 1, 3, 0, and 4.
>
> Note that the order of those five elements can be arbitrary.
>
> It doesn't matter what values are set beyond the returned length.
>   Clarification:
>
> Confused why the returned value is an integer but your answer is an
>   array?
>
> Note that the input array is passed in by reference, which means
>   modification to the input array will be known to the caller as well.
>
> Internally you can think of this:
>
> // nums is passed in by reference. (i.e., without making a copy) int
>   len = removeElement(nums, val);
>
> // any modification to nums in your function would be known by the
>   caller. // using the length returned by your function, it prints the
>   first len elements. for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
>       print(nums[i]); }

**My answer**:

```
int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.empty()) { return 0; }
    int end = nums.size() - 1;
    int curr_val = nums[end];
    for (; end > 0; end--){
        if(curr_val == nums[end - 1]){ // there is duplicate before this value (curr_val)
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + end - 1); // remove the duplicate at the particular index
        } else {
            curr_val = nums[end - 1];
        }
    }

    return nums.size();
}
```

**My execution time**

I submitted the same answer `five` times, and the execution time goes from `8ms` in the beginning to `4ms` , then to `0ms`. Why is the execution time so inconsistent? Does it have something to do with the Leetcode platform?

[image: Snapshot of all 5 submissions]

Comment: Execution is happening on their (Leetcode's) servers. And this seems perfectly fine. There's might be other running processes in their servers as well and there might be several other possible reasons as well. So, yes it's perfectly normal. Have you ever tried it locally, you'll see the difference in your computer as well? Try `time ./<executable>`

Comment: Other leetcode users [have reported the same](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/136683/different-run-time-with-same-code) observation. I'm not sure how this question can be answered here on SO aside from saying "yes, it is probably the platform".

Comment: Note that your algorithm has quadratic time complexity.

Comment: The shown code has a lot of room for improvement. The most efficient solution here will not use `erase()`, and `erase()` is going to get called every time a duplicate value is removed, which is horribly inefficient. The right solution will not use `erase()`, but just a single `for` loop that passes over the array once, followed by `resize()`. I would expect these kinds of techniques to be discussed in every good C++ textbook, which you should use, instead of sites like 'leetcode', if you are serious about gaining good C++ skills.

Comment: Code running in an unknown environment with an unknown amount of other work running in parallel and potentially running on different hardware each time, takes different amounts of time for each run; News at 11. Why is that surprising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeetCode doesn't claim to offer a hermetic and consistent environment for running your programs. You can imagine that they probably have hundreds or thousands of machines on which they run submissions. Some of them they probably bought five years ago, some are brand new, some are temporarily running more submissions than others, etc. There might be some kind of affinity mechanism that runs your submission the second and third time on the same server used for the first, possibly avoiding some initialization overhead. I've personally noticed that JavaScript submissions tend to run faster after the first submission even with no changes. When evaluating performance of your submissions, pay less attention to the absolute run time and more to the run time relative to other submissions. If you're practicing for an interview, the relative run time will tell you if you generally got the algorithm right in big-O terms. If you're a lot slower than the other submissions then you're probably using the wrong approach. In your case your run time is fantastic, so consider it done and move on!

Comment: Move on after writing a quadratic time algorithm for a problem that can be solved in linear time?

Comment: The question was about the LeetCode platform, not about this particular solution.

Comment: Also note that the submission for which the times are reported is not the one the OP included at the top of the question.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! And thank you @Evg for pointing out the run time problem. The quadratic one was actually my first answer to the question, and the one in the picture is my second.